# Karate: how to convert object/map in string from javascript to Java?

Tags: javascript, java, karate

I Have a file json named production_2.json

```
[
  {
     "v":{
        "id":"rep_01564526",
        "name":"tuttoverde.pgmx",
        "type":"PRODUCTION_STARTED",
        "ute":"CDL",
        "ver":"1.0",
        "status":"EXE"
     },
     "ts":"2020-11-19T08:00:00Z"
  },
  {
     "v":{
        "id":"rep_01564526",
        "name":"tuttoverde.pgmx",
        "type":"PRODUCTION_ENDED",
        "ute":"CDL",
        "ver":"1.0",
        "status":"EXE"
        
     },
     "ts":"2020-11-19T17:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

And have the folling Karate code, that:

1. Read the file production_2.json
2. and for each element of the array send a topic

```
I  * def sendtopics = 
     """
         function(i){
           
            var topic = "data." + machineID + ".Production";
            var payload = productions[i];
            karate.log('topic: ', topic )
            karate.log('payload: ', payload )
            return  mqtt.sendMessage(payload, topic);
            
         }
     """

    * def productions =  read('this:productions_json/production_2.json')
    * def totalProductionEvents = productions.length
    * def isTopicWasSent =  karate.repeat(totalProductionEvents, sendtopics)
    * match each isTopicWasSent == true
```

The function

```
mqtt.sendMessage(payload, topic);
```

is a function in java, that have the following segnature

```
public Boolean sendMessage(String payload, String topic) {

        System.out.println("Publishing message: ");
        System.out.println("payload " + payload);
        System.out.println("topic " + topic);
        return true;
      }
```

the problem is that **the value of the "payload"** inside the javascript function is correct and is printed **correctly**, while inside the "sendMessage" function the value of the **payload is formatted incorrectly**.

For example here is what it prints inside   karate.log('payload: ', payload )

```
payload:  {
  "v": {
    "id": "rep_01564526",
    "name": "tuttoverde.pgmx",
    "type": "PRODUCTION_STARTED",
    "ute": "CDL",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "status": "EXE"
  },
  "ts": "2021-01-08T08:00:00Z"
}
```

And Here instead what is printed on the function "sendMessage" of the java class

```
payload {v={id=rep_01564526, name=tuttoverde.pgmx, type=PRODUCTION_STARTED, ute=CDL, ver=1.0, status=EXE,  ts=2021-01-08T08:00:00Z}
```

I don't understand why the payload is formatted incorrectly (= instead of :  ) and is it not a string. I also tried using the following solution and it doesn't work for me

```
 * def sendtopics = 
     """
         function(i){
           
            var topic = "data." + machineID + ".Production";
            var payload = productions[i];
            var payload2 = JSON.stringify(payload);
            return  mqtt.sendMessage(payload2, topic);
            
         }
     """
```

How do I convert an object inside javascript to a string so I can pass it to java?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in this question. It seems the problem is not converting a JavaScript object to a string, the real problem appears to be pretty-printing in Java. @RachidG am I correct?

Comment: I would like the payload in java to be printed as a string. e.g.   {
  "v": {
    "id": "rep_01564526",
    "name": "tuttoverde.pgmx",
    "type": "PRODUCTION_STARTED",
    "ute": "CDL",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "status": "EXE"
  },
  "ts": "2021-01-08T08:00:00Z"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some really advanced stuff in Karate. I strongly suggest you start looking at the new version (close to release) and you can find details here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

The reason is because the async and Java interop has some breaking changes - and there are some new API-s you can call on the `karate` object in JS to do format conversions:

```
var temp = karate.fromString(payload);
```

And `karate.log()` should work better and not give you that odd formatting you are complaining about. With the current version you can try `karate.toJson()` if that gives you the conversion you expect.

Given your advanced usage, I recommend you start using the new version and provide feedback on anything that may be still needed.